# how to get "NA" value if radio button is not selected or disabled?

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to get value as "NA" if there is no radio button option is selected.
Right now i use this code `$("input[name='question']:checked").siblings('label').text()`
but by this code i am getting value as Blank if any radio button is not checked or question is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below sample code this might be helpful:

I have used the querySelector DOM method which uses common name porperty of radio buttons inside it.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="question" value="1"> Question1
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="question" value="2"> Question2
</label>
  
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  
       var getSelectedValue = document.querySelector( 'input[question="type"]:checked');   
       alert("getSelectedValue>>>"+getSelectedValue);
       if(getSelectedValue!= null)
       {
       console.log("radio button selected")
       }
       else{
       console.log("not selected")
       
       //here you can add your logic for 'NA'
       }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this `$("input[name='question']:checked").siblings('label').text() || "NA"` and it works.Let me know if iit is not a good practice.